# AVCaptureMovieFileOutput - no active/enabled connections

Tags: ruby, avfoundation, avcapturesession, rubymotion

In RubyMotion, I'm using AVFoundation for screencapture in an attempt to implement [this gist](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1740/_index.html) from the Mac Developer Library. The program should capture video from the screen and write to a .mov file.

I don't quite understand why I'm getting this error:

> *** -[AVCaptureMovieFileOutput startRecordingToOutputFileURL:recordingDelegate:] - no active/enabled
>   connections.

The simple code is:

```
# Setup recording pipeline
@session = AVCaptureSession.alloc.init
@session.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium
input = AVCaptureScreenInput.alloc.initWithDisplayID(KCGDirectMainDisplay)
@session.addInput(input)
movieFileOutput = AVCaptureMovieFileOutput.alloc.init
if @session.canAddOutput(movieFileOutput)
  @session.addOutput(movieFileOutput)
else
  Logger.error "Could not add ouput #{movieFileOutput}"
end
@session.startRunning()

# Delete exisiting file
fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager
path = "~/Desktop/video.mov"
if fileManager.fileExistsAtPath(path)
  err = Pointer.new(:object)
  unless fileManager.defaultManager.removeItemAtPath(path, error:err)
    Logger.error "Can't delete existing movie"
  end
end

# Start recording
movieFileOutput.startRecordingToOutputFileURL(NSURL.fileURLWithPath(path), recordingDelegate:self) # <--- Problem
```

What am I doing incorrect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used an incorrect constant for display id. This works:

`input = AVCaptureScreenInput.alloc.initWithDisplayID(CGMainDisplayID())`